# TOC shows 'Chapter A', but I want 'Appendix A'

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I am using a latex dissertation template provided by my university to write my dissertation and I'm currently having two issues with the appendix: (1) On the table of content (toc), my appendixes are named 'Chapter A', 'Chapter B', etc. whereas I want them to show as 'Appendix A', 'Appendix B', etc (none of the previously discussed solution on this forum worked). (2) The page number on each appendix page with the title 'Appendix [letter]' in the body of the document shifts to the bottom center, from the upper-right corner format used elsewhere. I feel like the two question are related which is why I'm asking them together, but I'd be more than happy to get help with either one separately.

My appendix is defined in a separate document named 'thesisU.cls', and I use the 'thesisU' as my document class. I also have a separate document named appendix.tex, where I called \appendix. The appendix code in the .cls document is as follows:

```
% Redefine appendix to print Appendix []. ... page # in table of contents.
\newcommand{\appnumberline}[1]{\advance\hangindent\@tempdima \hbox{Appendix #1. }}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
 \setcounter{chapter}{0}
 \setcounter{section}{0}
 \renewcommand\@chapapp{Appendix}
 \renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
% Redefine @chapter  so that appnumberline (ratherline) is used.
 \def\@chapter[##1]##2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
  \appnumberline{\thechapter}##1} \else 
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##1}\fi
  \chaptermark{##1}
```

I know this is not exactly compilable due to the multi file nature of the template, but any pointer as to how to solve the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the `thesisU` document class file available online?

Comment: You can put `\let\numberline=\appnumberline` in `\l@chapter` and leave everything esle as is.  `\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\numberline}{\appnumberline}{}{}` from etoolbox would be easier yet (do it after `\appendix`).